# Разделение постов в wordpress

Tags: post, php, wordpress

Есть сайт на вордпресс. Нужно сделать, чтобы страница "Блог Васи" выводила посты Васи, а страница "Блог Ивана" выводил посты Ивана. И чтобы эти посты ни как не должны пересекаться
P.S. Даже категории у них будут разные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понимаю то:
У вас есть статическая страница "Блог Васи" и статическая страница "Блог Пети"
Для каждой из этих страниц можно сделать свой шаблон.
Создаете на сайте 2 категории "Блог Васи" и "Блог Пети"
В шаблоне "Блог Васи" делаете вывод статей из категории "Блог Васи", а на странице "Блог Пети" делаете вывод статей из категории "Блог Пети".
Делается это очень легко:

```
$postlist=get_posts('category=Номер категории&numberposts=-1');
foreach ($postslist as $post) {
echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">- '.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
}
```

В этом примере я вывожу только заголовки и ссылки, тут же вы можете выводить и контент.
Только оформление сделайте своё.